# Javafx tableview row contextmenu bindings

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Per [this](https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/) link, I have added context menu to my tableview using the following pattern -

```
row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
      Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(row.itemProperty()))
      .then(rowMenu)
      .otherwise((ContextMenu)null));
```

I have a requirement where the multiple rows can be selected (`SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`) and I need to display the context menu when a row property matches a specific value. I have tried this but no luck -

```
// Show menu only if row is not null and value property == "foo"
row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
      Bindings.when(Bindings.and(Bindings.isNotNull(row.itemProperty()), Bindings.equal("foo", row.getItem().value))
      .then(rowMenu)
      .otherwise((ContextMenu)null));
```

*UPDATE*

I got this working via a listener -

```
        row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
            if (isEmpty) {
                row.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {
                if (row.getItem().name.get().equals("foo")) {
                    row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                }
            }
        });
```

Question - Is there a way to achieve this using the `Bindings` API?

Answer (score 0):

Your binding does this:

```
Bindings.equal("foo", row.getItem().value)
```

But your listener does this:

```
row.getItem().name.get().equals("foo")
```

So perhaps, using this in the binding would work:

```
Bindings.equal("foo", row.getItem().name.get())
```

Comment: The Bindings.equal signature requires the 2nd arg to be a Observable not a String

Comment: So leave out the ".get()"